# Drawing in layers to a LibGDX FrameBuffer

Tags: java, memory, textures, libgdx, framebuffer

I am working on a mobile game project using LibGDX that requires me to combine several sprites together and draw them into a FBO.  Basically, I am trying to draw groups of sprites to a texture at 1.0 alpha so I can draw those textures back to the FBO at a lower opacity and it will look like one big piece.  The problem I am having is that I need to make several of these and the textures can end up being quite large, and creating all of these textures and retaining all of them at once does not sound like an ideal solution at all.

What I am trying to do instead is work with the textures one at a time from within the FBO itself, which I *think* sounds feasible, but I cannot quite figure out how to make that work either.  In order to combine the sprites onto a texture, like I described earlier, I believe I need to do that drawing in a separate FBO and get the texture from that.  I am not sure how efficient stopping/starting FBO's is, but even just as a test I tried to stop the main FBO, draw to the temporary one that is used to make each of these textures, and then restart the main one and draw that created texture, but it didn't seem to work at all.  I assume it was because FBOs weren't meant to be toggled back and forth quite like that, but I am unsure what else to try.

I hope my explanation wasn't too confusing with all the switching between FBOs and what not, but basically I am just looking for the best way to create multiple textures from within the app and then draw each of those textures individually to a FBO without having to retain all of those textures in memory at one time.

This is a stripped down version of what I was trying to do.

```
public static void processImage() {
    mainFBO.begin();
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // draw in background texture(s)
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLayers; i++){
            mainFBO.end();
            Texture tempTexture = processLayer();
            mainFBO.begin();
            // draw tempTexture with desired settings

    }
    mainFBO.end();

    finalTexture = mainFBO.getColorBufferTexture();
}

public static Texture processLayer() {
    secondaryFBO.begin();
    // Draw all sprites for the necessary "layer"
    secondaryFBO.end();

    return secondaryFBO.getColorBufferTexture();
}
```

Comment: Switching drawing among mutilple FBOs and the screen should work.  You'll need to show some code to make it clearer what you're trying to accomplish and to get some more precise feedback about what may be wrong.

Comment: I added a bit of pseudo code that shows pretty much what I was trying to do.  All of the typical initialization and blend mode stuff is there too of course, but I figured that would just make it harder to read if I included it.  If that setup looks like it should work fine I will have to experiment further to see where the problem  may be, but right now it seems like it just doesn't work this way.

Comment: Looks like it should work.  Can you expand on "didn't seem to work at all"?

Comment: Based on your code I don't see anything really wrong with it, could you provide screenshots of what it is doing, maybe show some more code related to how you render it and also and image of what you might be expecting to see?